# replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z]", "") but using lua

Tags: lua

please tell me an analogue of a C ++ function but in lua

```
replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z]", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lua's [patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) for that (which are not to be confused with regular expressions), in combination with [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub).

In your case, it's probably something like

```lua
local sanitized = raw:gsub("[^%dA-Za-z]", "")
```

(I don't have access to a Lua REPL at the moment, so this code is untested, but the links to the documentation should help you if in doubt)

Comment: `"[^%dA-Za-z]"` can be simplified to `"%W"` but your "literal translation" of that rexgex is also correct of course

Comment: @Piglet Yeah, I used `%w` first, but then was unsure what it would treat non-ANSI characters (like German Umlauts) like, that's why I changed it to the 'expanded' pattern later on

Comment: German Umlauts are also not covered by a-z so there is no difference I guess

Comment: I was unsure if they were covered by %w. The question seems to be related to sanitizing input, so if %w _includes_ Umlauts, while a-z _excludes_ them, that could lead to all kinds of trouble... I guess OP'll have to try it out for their use case